# Python: assign a list to a function

Tags: python

Is there a way to assign a list based on a variable env and pass the result to function? I am passing a variable called env, which could be UPE, DEV, PRD for example. Based on the result, I want to assign the list respectively to the functions below. What would be the best approach?

```py
UPE=['SERVER1','SERVER2','SERVER3','SERVER4']
DEV=['ServerA','ServerB']
PRD=['SERVER1','SERVER2','SERVER3','SERVER4']

if os.path.isfile('/myfile/' + configFile):

  config_parser = ConfigParser()
  config_parser.read('/myfile/' + configFile)

if actions == "start":
    startOVD('start',UPE[3]) //I want pass the result of env setup variable
    #ans = raw_input("Would you like to start OVD, MSAS,OAG : y | n : ")
    if env == 'UPE':
        startMSAS('start',UPE[0])
        startOAG('start',UPE[1])
    startOHS('start',UPE[2])
    for section_name in sorted(config_parser.sections(), reverse=True):
        adminURL = config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_URL')
        adminUsername = config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_USER')
        adminPassword = config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_PASS')
        adminHost = config_parser.get(section_name, 'NM_HOST')
        domainName = config_parser.get(section_name, 'DOMAIN_NAME')
        domainDir = config_parser.get(section_name, 'DOMAIN_DIR')
        admPort = adminURL[-4:]

        printHeader('Initiating Starting Sequence')
        startAdmin('start', adminHost, domainDir, domainName, admPort)
        showServerStatus('start', adminUsername, adminPassword, adminURL)


if actions == "stop":
    for section_name in (config_parser.sections()):
        adminURL = config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_URL')
        adminUsername = config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_USER')
        adminPassword = config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_PASS')
        adminHost = config_parser.get(section_name, 'NM_HOST')
        domainName = config_parser.get(section_name, 'DOMAIN_NAME')
        domainDir = config_parser.get(section_name, 'DOMAIN_DIR')
        admPort = adminURL[-4:]

        printHeader('Initiating Stopping Sequence')
        showServerStatus('stop', adminUsername, adminPassword, adminURL)
        stopAdmin(adminHost, domainDir, domainName, admPort)

    if env == 'UPE':
        stopMSAS('stop',UPE[0])
        stopOAG('stop',UPE[1])
    stopOHS('stop',UPE[2])
    stopOVD('stop',UPE[3])
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit with what you are asking? i.e. what do you mean by pass the `list` to the `functions`. What list and what functions?

Comment: I don't see a function but rather a bunch of conditionals. Where is this function you are speaking about.

Comment: What I am trying to do is if my list varialbe are for example:

    UPE_ENV=['AMPOMSU01','AMPOAGU01','ampwt12u01','AMPDSU01']
    DEV_ENV=['AMPOMSD01','AMPOAGD01','ampwt12d01','AMPDST01']

I pass env variable that could be DEV, UPE

   startOVD('start',env+'_ENV'[3]) 

I want to get the value of DEV_ENV[3] for example if my env= DEV

Answer (score 0):

I would organize this by setting up a list of callbacks.

```
from functools import partial

start_funcs = [partial(startOVD 'start',UPE[3])
if env == 'UPE':
    start_funcs.extend([partial(startMSAS, 'start', UPE[0]),
                       partial(startOAG, 'start', UPE[1])])
start_funcs.append(partial(startOHS, 'start', UPE[2]))
```

Add similar logic for the cases when `env` has a different value. In the end, you'll just iterate over `start_funcs` and call each function in order.

```
if actions == "start":
    for f in start_funcs:
        f()

    # ...
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is if my list varialbe are for example: 

     UPE_ENV=['AMPOMSU01','AMPOAGU01','ampwt12u01','AMPDSU01']  
     DEV_ENV=['AMPOMSD01','AMPOAGD01','ampwt12d01','AMPDST01']

I pass [env] variable that could be DEV, UPE 

I have a function that I want to pass the value of DEV_ENV[3]. 
   
    startOVD('start',env+'_ENV'[3]) I want to get the dynamic value of DEV_ENV[3]

Comment: Don't do that. Create a dict like `env = {'UPE': ['AMPOMSU01', ...], 'DEV': ['AMPOMSD01', ...]}`.